# Articulate Storyline - proceed to next slide after filling feedback form (minimum amount of words)?

Tags: javascript, articulate

There's a way to proceed to next slide only after filling the feedback form in Articulate Storyline - but, is there a way to let the learner write a minimum amount of words in the feedback form, before proceeding to next slide?

I know Javascript is used for this but I am not that proficient.

Can anybody help?

Tried some javascript but did not work. Would rather ask for fresh perspective.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Edit your question, and put what you have already tried.  Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)